# Command line output misaligned

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal, fonts

I notice my terminal output was misaligned. I installed many packages and even did once upgrade from Debian 9 to 10 recently, and when I notice this small issue, it is a bit late. Does anyone get similar issue before and know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a different font is being used for the bold output, perhaps the font that is configured for normal output does not have a bold variant. It's not a command-line problem but a problem with the configuration of the fonts for your terminal emulator.

Comment: What terminal emulator, what font?

Comment: See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/issues/137. Summary: either freetype version 2.10, or – assuming you're using a VTE-based terminal emulator – VTE version 0.58 fixes this problem.

Comment: After switching to non-variable fonts, it works! Thanks @egmont